# Copy multiple hits in one line

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file with a single line like this:     class="Foo" *irrelevant stuff* (+string) *irrelevant stuff* class="Foo" *irrelevant stuff* (+string) *irrelevant stuff*...
I need to collect every string inside (), there are up to 200 in the line.

I can only think of adding a new line after each class and the running egrep.

I use sed 's/class="Foo"/\n/g' to create new lines after each class. Then I use egrep '(+.*)' to filter out all strings i need and then sed again to kill the () and +.

Comment: post the input content

Comment: well its hard for me as this varies, i need only the base approach how  to get grep non greedy or if there is any program that acts like so. inpunt is a huge string with .html class strings, where i need to copy every string inside a ()

Comment: No surprise that your input varies. But you still have to create some representative sample input. Several lines, which vary through examples of what migth occur. With your current question the regexes would probably use "~ (" and ") ~" for anchoring. Give the desired output, to give a different way of defining what you want to collect/print. You could also provide the code for your "adding a newline". Simply because it might clarify what the actual goal is. If you give more information, one of the multi-thousand-reputation sed gurus will be able to  help. Is it always the same number of "()"?

Comment: i use sed 's/slass="Foo"/\n/g' to create newlines after each class.

Comment: I would like to understand your solution. Could you elaborate? Maybe you could even create an answer, a Q/A pair which matches your problem would be nicer than a Q/comment pair. Also an MCVE would be nice to make the question clearer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Then here is my second shot:
I a File, i contains only one line, but a very long one. Inside the line are multiple classes

```
class="Foo"
```

after each class like this there is somewhere

```
(+Bar)
```

Between these patters are random digits letters ans symbols and repeats itself up to 200 times. the inside of (+.*) is different for each repetition.

I need to eliminate EVERYTHING inside the file but the string contained in (+), and creat a newline after each string.

So i get an output like this

```
bar1
bar2
...
barn
```

Right now im doing this so:

```
sed 's/class="Foo"/\n/g'
```

So i get a line for each class.

```
egrep '\(+.*\)' -o
```

To find the string inside (+), after that 2 times sed to kill the ( and ).

It does exactly what i want, but i want to know if there is a better way for this.